# Evaluate the integration $\int_{|z|=100}f(z)\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let , $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}.\frac{1-2z}{z-2}\cdots \frac{1-10z}{z-10}$$Find $$\int_{|z|=100}f(z)\,dz$$

We find that the function $f(z)$ has simple pole at the points $z=0,2,4,6,8,10$ , and all the points lie in $|z|=100$. So the required integral equal to $2\pi i\times\text{sum of the residues}$. But that process is too much laborious in this case.

Does there any other simplest way to evaluate the integral ?

Comment: $\left|\frac{1-az}{z-a}\right|=1$ on the unit circle.

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment because I'm not very confident: Following @A.G. 's hint, a variation of the Schwarz reflection principle shows that $f$ satisfies $f(z)=1/\overline{f(1/\bar{z})}$ and the desired integral is equivalent to
$$
\int_{|z|=1/100}\frac{1}{\overline{f(\bar{z})}}\,dz
$$ 
The Schwarz reflection shows that $1/\overline{f(1/\bar{z})}$ is meromorphic, and precomposing with $1/z$ doesn't change this. Computing shows that it is holomorphic within the new contour. This (should) show that our desired integral is zero.

Comment: @Blake One more thing: when doing the inversion $1/z$ one has to recalculate $dz$ too, which becomes $d(1/z)=-dz/z^2$ and sets a pole at zero. But it is just *one* residue to calculate.

Comment: @A.G. There I got forgetting how to substitute. Thanks

Comment: @Blake [Here is a link](https://books.google.se/books?id=uYYpdrbKJTEC&pg=PA153#v=onepage&q&f=false) on residue at infinity

Comment: @Blake One more thing.  The mapping reverses the orientation of the contour.  So, watch out for that minus sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inasmuch as all of the singularities are contained within $|z|<100$, we can evaluate the contour integral by finding the [Residue at Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity).  To do this, we evaluate

$$\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=\infty\right)=\text{Res}\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right),z=0\right)$$

Now, given $f(z)=\frac1z\prod_{n=2,n even}^{10}\frac{1-nz}{z-n}$, we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f\left(\frac1z\right)=z\prod_{n=2,n even}^{10}\frac{z-n}{1-nz}}$$

Therefore,

$$\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=\infty\right)=-\lim_{z\to 0}\left(\prod_{n=2,n even}^{10}\frac{z-n}{1-nz}\right)=\prod_{n=2,n even}^{10}\,n=3840$$

Finally, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\oint_{|z|=100} f(z)\,dz=-2\pi i (3840)}$$